# How to install extension from 'bin' file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have downloaded "SQLite for Windows Runtime (Windows 8.1)" from extensions web site (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1d04f82f-2fe9-4727-a2f9-a2db127ddc9a).  It has .bin format.

How can I install it ?

Comment: When I download that file, I get a ".vsix" file as expected.  Did your download fail?

Comment: Thanks, it helps me.  I have downloaded file using Chrome on Linux and it changed extension to 'bin'.